# Scenarios for using ':=' vs '=' in makefile? (With examples if possible)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I started digging into details of makefile recently. I understand that ':=' is immediate and '=' is deferred. However, I need some simplified scenarios/examples of when I need to use one versus the other in order to fully appreciate the difference.

Comment: `:=` is evaluated only once while `=` is re-evaluated on each reference. Consider this scenario: `TEMPFILE=$(shell mktemp /tmp/XXXXXXXX)`. When you reference `TEMPFILE` it will be different in each reference. If that's intended then `=` will work. If the intent is to reference the previously created `TEMPFILE`, in that the wanted effect is to use the same file all throughout the steps in the `Makefile`, then `:=` should be used instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `.foo` and `.bar` files had exactly the same recipe you wouldn't want to have to write it out twice, recursively expanded variables to the rescue:

```
foobar = do_stuff $@
%.foo:
    $(foobar)
%.bar:
    $(foobar)
```

Unless you need recursive expansion, simply expanded variables should be used by default as they are easier to reason about and more robust.

```
some_deps = stuff I really want
some_other_deps = $(some_deps) some more

### [...]

some_deps = unrelated stuff

foo: $(some_other_deps) # Oops, should have used := for some_other_deps
```

You can find more examples in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors).

Comment: Thank you for referencing this section of the manual. I totally missed this part of it.